# stargazer not formatting in a table in RMD file

Tags: r, r-markdown, stargazer

I ran a couple of simple OLS and used stargazer as below

```
stargazer(reg01, reg02, type="html")
```

However, the output in the RMD file simply lists the elements in rows not in a nice table
Any idea why this is happening?

[image: 1]

Thank you for your help!

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a minimal working code or Rmd and a snippet of the data or some fake data to run the code.

Comment: Try to add the option`results='asis'` to your code chunk

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you are trying to render to a PDF format (`output: pdf_document`), but give the table the type of a HTML file.

Here is a MWE with the correct YAML header for type = "html". For the next time, please add a complete [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

````
---
output: html_document
---

```{r results='asis'}
## OLS models
library(stargazer)
linear.1 <- lm(rating ~ complaints + privileges + learning + raises + critical,
data=attitude)
linear.2 <- lm(rating ~ complaints + privileges + learning, data=attitude)
## create an indicator dependent variable, and run a probit model
attitude$high.rating <- (attitude$rating > 70)
probit.model <- glm(high.rating ~ learning + critical + advance, data=attitude,
family = binomial(link = "probit"))
stargazer(linear.1, linear.2, probit.model, title="Results", type="html")
```
````